# typing error when passing id parameter in nest js

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have an application in nest js that is connected with mongo db from mongoose and that receives the id as a parameter but whenever I send a request to delete it shows an error

the error

```
 ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cast to ObjectId failed for value "61f7ae5e39160a545dea72d6\n" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Stock"
```

the service

```
 async remove(id: string) {
    //return await this.stockModel.deleteOne({id: id});
    return await this.stockModel.deleteOne({ _id: id }).exec();
    
  }
```

the controller

```
@Delete(':id')
  remove(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.stockService.remove(id);
  }
```

Comment: your id has a "\n" remove it and it should fix the problem

Comment: @sinabariaji but I made a console.log in the service and it returns the id without the "/n"

Comment: please provide the code of how you sending the id

Comment: console.log wont print the `\n` as it would simply drop a line. try using `return await this.stockModel.deleteOne({ _id: id.trim() }).exec();` - note the `trim()` method on the string id. if that doesnt work then you need to post more information

Comment: @sinabariaji that was it was just add the trim. thanks

Comment: @HagaiKalinhoff that was it was just add the trim. thanks